# How to prove there exists a positive integer $k,d$ such $\sum_{i=1}^{2k}a_{id}=k-2014$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a non-negative integer such that: for any postive integer
$m,n$, we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2m}a_{in}\le m.$$
Show that
 there exist positive integers $k,d$ such that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2k}a_{id}=k-2014.$$

I'm really struggling to find a solution. Here's what I have so far:

First, let $m=1$. We then have:
$$a_{1n}+a_{2n}\le 1,\forall n\in N^{+}$$
Let
$m=2$; thus, we have:
$$a_{1n}+a_{2n}+a_{3n}+a_{4n}\le 2,\forall n\in N^{+}$$
Let
$m=3$. Then we have
$$a_{1n}+a_{2n}+a_{3n}+a_{4n}+a_{5n}+a_{6n}\le 3,\forall n\in N^{+}.$$